# Ubuntu in Azure DNS Name Change

Tags: azure

I was wondering if I could change the DNS name on one of our azure servers from ######.cloudapp.net to mail.flyboeingva.org?

If so, how would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can!

follow the tutorial [Configure a custom domain name for Azure cloud service](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/cloud-services-custom-domain-name/). Further more, if you are going to host e-mail server on azure, you may also want to:

- [Reserve an IP Address for your cloud service](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/virtual-networks-reserved-public-ip/) (your VM runs in a cloud service, don't get confused by the terms)
- [Register Reverse DNS record (PTR)](http://azure.microsoft.com/blog/2014/07/21/announcing-reverse-dns-for-azure-cloud-services/) for your cloud service / custom domain